# Google sheets using Filter and Sort together

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

This is my first question here. I hope it's ok.
I'm a bit of a newbie using google sheets but I'm slowly progressing.

I'm trying to build a sheet with all my data in sheet 1.
On sheet 2 I would like to Filter all the data from sheet 2 that is marked with the number "1" in column D.
For that purpose, I'm using

```
=FILTER('Ark1'!A2:C999; 'Ark1'!D2:D999=1)
```

So far so good. It works.

Then I would like to sort this sheet based on the value in column E.
For that purpose, I'm using

```
=sort(FILTER('Ark1'!A2:C999; 'Ark1'!D2:D999=1);'Ark1'!E2:E999; SAND)
```

I get an I/T error. In danish it says:

> SORT har forskellige intervalstørrelser. Forventede 2 rækker og 1 kolonner, men indeholder 998 rækker og 1 kolonner.

Google translated to:

> > SORT has different range sizes. Expected 2 rows and 1 columns, but contains 998 rows and 1 columns.

I have a copy of the sheet here which is editable for your help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eh8aBnXH-SbqHyuvvmaCMc9eoNwZvoAtulxeJXB5-bE/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=SORT(FILTER('Ark1'!A2:C999; 'Ark1'!D2:D999=1); 5; 0)
```

or:

```
=SORT(FILTER('Ark1'!A2:C999; 'Ark1'!D2:D999=1); 5; 1)
```