# Creating a dynamically sorted and filtered list from a range using a single formula in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filtering, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to do something similar to this question: [Google sheets using Filter and Sort together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405451/google-sheets-using-filter-and-sort-together)

I have an input range with two columns, and as output I want to create a dynamically sorted and filtered list from the input range, using a single formula.

See this document for the desired result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/109xcbORFZxTjH0Vjd6PVqYlOxMIdK7aXqf5-jnMMPik/edit?usp=sharing

I tried the formula: `=SORT(FILTER(B11:C100, B11:B100 = or(I11,I12,I13,I14)), 2, 0)` but it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong here? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(B11:C, 
 "where lower(B) matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(I11:I))&"' 
  order by C desc", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution @player0 - I see that the QUERY function is very powerful. I have updated the Google Sheet with your solution.

Comment: Question: If I only wanted to render the first column (in our example the column with the Character names, and NOT the column with the frequency), what modification to the formula would be needed?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(B11:B, 
 "where lower(B) matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(I11:I))&"'", 0))`

Comment: Hm.. but the first column should still be sorted as before. Is there a way to hide the second column?

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(B11:C, 
 "select B where lower(B) matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(I11:I))&"' 
  order by C desc", 0))`

Comment: Aha! I see. Thank you! by the way, what do you recommend as a good reference to learn how  the QUERY function works?

Comment: try: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 2):

You can modified or(,,,,) like follow:

```
=SORT(
       FILTER(B11:C100, 
                ((B11:B100 = I11)*1+(B11:B100 = I12)*1+(B11:B100 = I13)*1+(B11:B100 = I14)*1)>0
       )
       , 2, 0
     )
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see @player0 's solution using QUERY